# Power BI visualization of data with a Start and End date

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, datefilter

[THis is an example of what I think i need to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02fmg.png)

I would like to ask some modeling advise I cannot solve myself:

I am using Power BI to visualize the time machinery is out of order.
The source is a register of equipment not functioning, with a start date and end date (note that there is no end date if the machine is not fixed yet).

I would like to show the time (hours, percentage, etc) that the machinery is out of order, filter for a specific period /date (e.g. month).

So I have 2 date columns: ‘’Start out of order’’  and ‘’Back in order’’

I do have a date table, which I usually would connect to all the date variables. However, since I am working with a Start and End date. This does not give the result I am looking for.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Kind regards,

Link to my Power BI FILE: 
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/83ca3850392967d0d42a5cc71f4352c420200213160932/eb7353

Stijn

Comment: Do you have code examples that you can share? That is always helpful.

Comment: Dear PlushyObject, Thank you for your reply. Basicly what I am trying to do in Power BI is split the row with a period (start and end date) in to unique rows with the days within the period. I have added an immage ilustrating what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how you would like to visualise your data, but this is what I managed to do:

create a daysdiff column with

```
Daysbetween = IF(ISBLANK(TF_Eventos
       [End out of order]);DATEDIFF(TF_Eventos[Start out of
       order];TF_Eventos[TODAY];HOUR);DATEDIFF(TF_Eventos
       [Start out of order];TF_Eventos[End out of order];HOUR))
```

This creates your column to check difference between Dates. 
Then create a separate column with your Date. In this case I copied the Start out of order date, since I thought you might wanted to be able to filter for the start dates. Then simply create a relationship between your newly created Date column and your start out of order date.

Doing so lets you create a visual with the daysbetween (in this case portrayed in hours) and your start dates. Now just simply add a slicer and you can filter on date.
[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you Raymond for your reply. This is indeed a usefull formula. However, does not answer my question. The end goal is to be able to visualize the '' hours out of order' over time. Therefore, I think i need to split the rows in days the machine is out of time with an unique date stamp. I tried to illustrate this in the image (link) in my original post. I will also add the Power BI File showing the data.

Comment: Do you perhaps have data we can actually download to try and solve your problem without having to type everything to power bi? When I look at your data you might want to create a new column based on an IF statement. for example 'Daysbetween = IF(ISBLANK([End Out of order]);DATEDIFF('your_table'[Start out of order];'your_table'[TODAY];HOUR);DATEDIFF('your_table'[Start out of order];'your_table'[End out of order];HOUR). So, if end date is empty you take the diff between start and todays date, else you return the diff between start and end

Comment: Dear Raymon, Thank you for your reaction. Your comment is indeed a way how to calculate the difference in hours. However, It will still not solve my problem of how to visualize it an be able to slice it over time. Ok, I added a link to my file in the question: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/83ca3850392967d0d42a5cc71f4352c420200213160932/eb7353

Comment: Dear Raymond, Thanks again for your reply and effort to help me. Although we are getting close, the real problem has not been solved: In the example illustration, you now see: Jan 12, 800 hours out of order. Lets say this is one machine, this means it is 34 days out of order, starting from 12 jan (800 / 24 = 33.33). Therefore, it should show 24 hours out of order, for each day its out of order (until 15th of Feb.). Hope this makes sence! Regards

Comment: So basicly this is what I am trying to do: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Turn-Start-Date-amp-End-Date-columns-into-one-column-with/td-p/210246

Comment: I get what you want to do now. There are multiple ways you can do this. You could either go the long route and make columns for every day by doing Jan1 = IF(DAYSBETWEEN>24;24;DAYSBETWEEN) and for jan2 = IF(Jan1<24;0;IF(DAYSBETWEEN - 24 >24;24;DAYSBETWEEN-24)) and so on. This is quite a long process though, but it will get the job done. Or you could make a While loop. For this I recommend you look at https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/For-and-While-Loops-in-DAX/ba-p/636314 This is not completely the same, but I think you could manage to do this for your problem. Hope this helps